# Running old versions of Macromedia Shockwave in a modern browser

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, internet-explorer

I'm trying to find ways to run Macromedia Shockwave 8 or 8.5 in a modern browser. So far, I have yet to find any methods besides running Adobe Shockwave 12 and hoping for the best. Is there a way to do this, or do I have to find an old browser? The installer for older versions of Shockwave do not install for modern browsers, but I can not find a way to install an older browser like IE5.

Is there a modern method, or am I completely out of luck?

Comment: why do you want to do this? what browser do you want to run it on?

Answer (score 1):

A virtual PC running Windows XP or even Windows 2000 may be the best way to run such legacy software.